# Generic class type constraint with a generic class having another constraint

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

Let's say I have a generic class

```
public class G<T> {
}
```

and I want to declare final class as

```
public class F<T> where T : G<T> {
}
```

that seems to be possible, but what if I want to complicate the task and add a constraint to the class G like that

```
public class A {
}

public class DA : A {
}

public class DB : A {
}

public class G<T> where T : A {
}
```

and finally I want to do this

```
public class F<T> where T : G<T> {
}
```

that does not work, it says T has to be of type A which is understandable and it looks like I can rewrite it like this

```
public class F<T, U> where T : G<U> where U : A {
}
```

but in this case the usage has a redundant declaration

```
public class DF : F<G<DA>, DA> {
}
```

I have to repeat DA twice when using class F even though it is quite clear if I use G as a generic type the generic type of G is DA. Is there a way to avoid this redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

> And finally I want to do this
>
> ```
> public class F<T> where T : G<T> {
> }
> ```

But this doesn't seem to make much sense. You want `F` to be parametrized by `T` which must be `G<X>` where `X` is `T` again, which is `G<X>`, where `X` is `T` again and so on... This is a recursive definition.

I think what you actually want to define is something like (all examples are invalid C#)

```
public class F<T1<T2>> where T1 : G<T2> where T2 : A {
}
```

or maybe

```
public class F<T1> where T1 : G<T2> where T2 : A {
}
```

or maybe

```
public class F<G<T>> where T : A {
}
```

Those kind of "generics of generics" are called *higher-kinded types*, but C#, unfortunately, does not support them. Haskell does for instance and some other functional languages do too.

There is a [C# library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext#ad-hoc-polymorphism) that mimics HKTs and it uses the workaround you found: specifying the inner type twice.

Comment: You can't declare a `class F<G<T>>` but of course you can instantiate nested generic types. `Dictionary<int, List<List<int>>> foo` is a perfectly valid type.

Comment: @PMF [Higher-kinded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) are something very different from nested generics.

Comment: @PMF Taking your example a higher-kinded type would be something like `Dictionary<int, T<int>` where `T` is expected to be not only a `List`, but any kind of generic type with rank 1 and parametrizable to `int`.

Comment: I have understood what it is about, even though I do not really see the use. Yes, I cannot declare a generic as `Dictionary<int, T<int>>`, but I still can declare all concrete types that could be made from such a class.

Comment: An example use would be an extension function `To()` that converts an `IEnumerable<T>` into any `TCollection<T>`: `List<int> l = new[] { 1 }.To<List<int>>()`. Not very spectacular, but this is just scratching the surface of what HKTs can do.